# How to edit trigger so that when a value drops below a threshold it notifies an email?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, create-table

I've created a table for the managers that have the columns itemNum, onHand, and managerEmail. The table I've created the trigger on is Item. What i'm trying to do is have me trigger listen in on itemNum and onHand for three specific items and if the onHand in the Item tables falls bellow the onHand in supplyNotify it notifies the email. For example, jruss@tal.com would need to be notified when the itemNum AA01 falls below 10 from an insert or update which is the itemNum in supplyNotify. The approach I tried to take was do a

```
where < threshold
```

in the if statements of the trigger and notify the email but I don't know how to go about this.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[supplyNotify](
    itemNum char(4),
    onHand decimal(4,0),
)

alter table supplyNotify
add managerEmail char(50)
go

alter table supplynotify 
add constraint managerEmail check (managerEmail like '%@tal.com%')
go

insert into supplyNotify
values
('AA01', 10, 'jruss@tal.com')
go

insert into supplyNotify
values
('BB02', 11, 'eperez@tal.com')
go

insert into supplyNotify
values
('CC03', 12, 'msimm@tal.com')
go

sp_CONFIGURE 'show advanced', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_CONFIGURE 'Database Mail XPs', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

use msdb
go

create trigger trg_insertAudit
on item
after insert, update
as
begin
if exists(select itemNum, OnHand from inserted where OnHand < 10)
begin
    insert into supplyNotify
    (itemNum, OnHand)
    select ItemNum, OnHand
    from inserted
    exec sp_send_dbemail @recipients = 'jruss@tal.com',
        @body = 'OnHand has fallen below 10'
end

if exists(select itemNum, OnHand from inserted where OnHand < 11)
begin
    insert into supplyNotify
    (itemNum, OnHand)
    select ItemNum, OnHand
    from inserted
    exec sp_send_dbemail @recipients = 'eperez@tal.com',
        @body = 'OnHand has fallen below 10'
end

if exists(select itemNum, OnHand from inserted where OnHand <12)
begin
    insert into supplyNotify
    (itemNum, OnHand)
    select ItemNum, OnHand
    from inserted
    exec sp_send_dbemail @recipients = 'msimm@tal.com',
        @body = 'OnHand has fallen below 10'
end

if (update(itemNum) or update(OnHand))
 begin
    print 'ItemNum or onHand column was updated '
end

end
go
```

Comment: your trigger has some interesting logic. For starters the if exists will ALWAYS be true. Exists checks for the existence of rows, not values. Also, the UPDATE functions checks to see if that column is in the update statement and returns true even if the value has not changed. For the question at hand you need to look at the values in the inserted virtual table. You need to provide more details about what you are expecting here. And really shouldn't OnHand be a computed column?

Comment: @Sean Lange So i'm missing an argument for update to filter out a 'null' update basically?  From my understanding of triggers I know that when a trigger is triggered a prompt is displayed showing something such as "1 row affected". What I want to do is notify the manager when the trigger is triggered. So jruss@tal.com is notified when the item AA01 falls below 10 in OnHand in the Item table.

Comment: What I am saying about your exists check is that it is pointless as coded. If you want to exclude NULL then you need to add a where predicate. For the notification you could send an email. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx

Comment: @SeanLange I edited the code, I added a where predicate and looked at the link you posted and came up with the above. I saw that I had to configure mail database and then i added an exec for each if statement to send an email. Although when I wrote sp_send_dbemail it tells me it could not find the stored procedure?

Comment: You should look closely at the name of the procedure. There is no "e" in it. Also, with your newest logic you will send 3 emails when the quantity is < 10 and the body of the email is exactly the same in each one. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: @SeanLange Corrected it, I took out the 'e' and edited the body thank you for pointing that out wasn't what I was trying to do. For some reason i'm still getting "Could not find store procedure 'sp_send_dbmail'

Comment: It lives in msdb. To call it you will need to add the database name. Like this. "exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail [Your parameters here]"

Comment: @SeanLange Got it, so when I want to use another database I just use [databasename].dbo...

Comment: Yes. Well actually it may not always be dbo, that should be the name of the schema where the object you are referencing exists.